# Storing user specific data using HTML local storage

Tags: jquery, html

In my web application, I want to store the search keywords used by a specific user using local storage so that I can show these search terms later when that user tries to search again.

I distinguish each user with their username (which is unique) and every time they type and search something, I use their username as keys and that string as item.

```
$('#search-submit').on('click', function(){

    var keyword = $('#search-input').val();
    localStorage.setItem(username,keyword);
    //....
}
```

But this overwrites the key-item pair each time.

Is there any way I can store multiple items while keeping them associated with the same username?

Comment: Make the keyword a more elaborate data structure like an array or JSON string ?

Comment: Local storage is Local to the user, not to the server, so you're just storing it on the users computer. There is no use for the username, just store it in a JSON array.

Comment: @Darren while that is going to be the case MOST of the time, by storing the username as the key it will prevent conflicts between say a husband and wife that both use your application on the same computer. MAYBE you'd want to namespace it as `localStorage['myApp.username'] = keywords`

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the entry exists, if so just append the new data instead of overwriting it:

```
function saveKeyword(name, keyword) {
    var exists = false;
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (key === name) {
            exists = true;
        }
    }

    if (exists) {
        var temp = localStorage.getItem(name);
        localStorage.setItem(name, temp + ', ' + keyword);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(name, keyword);
    }
}
```